# two dictionaries, making a list

Tags: python, file, list, function, dictionary

Alright so this is a bit complicated. I have a function that accepts two dictionary parameters created via txt files that have already been returned in other functions.  The countries parameter has a three letter country code as key and the corresponding country as value.  the medals dictionary has said three letter code as key but with a set containing four integers that correspond to # of games, gold medals, silver medals, and bronze medals respectively.  The function is to accept a three letter country code loop through the medals dictionary and see if the code is a key in the medals dictionary. Three possibilities can occur: If it is, then it's supposed to create a list formatted like so: `[
[‘Country’,’Code’,’Gold’,’Silver’,’Bronze’],
[‘Great Britain’
,
‘GRE’
,800, 400, 750]
]`.  This part compiles and makes a list, but the games part needs to be removed from the medal key value and returned as a branched list rather than a tuple/set thing. If the string is not a key in the dictionary, then if the string is empty, it adds every single country with the above formatting into a list. this part isn't compiling because i'm for looping on the fly wrong i think. if the string is not empty and not in the dictionary, it returns `[INVALID CODE, n/a]`. That part works i'm pretty sure. Here's my code:

```
def findMedals(countries, medals):
    some_strng = input("input a three letter country code and i'll see if I can find it: ")
    reference  = ['Country','Code','Gold','Silver','Bronze']
    medalList= [reference]
    for key in medals.items():
        if some_strng in key:
            medalList.append([countries[some_strng],key,medals[some_strng]])
            break
        if not some_strng in key:
            if some_strng == '':
                medalList.append([countries[some_string], key for key in countries,medals[some_strng] for key in medals])
            else:
                medalList.append(['INVALID CODE', 'n/a'])
    print(medalList)    
    return(medalList)
    findMedals(country('CountryCodes.txt'),medals('GoldMedals.txt'))
```

Comment: Please, fix your code's formatting.

Comment: Why not just fix the indentation, rather than having a note about it? Also, do you want people to read your wall of words?

Comment: Should probably fix the unclosed string as well...

Comment: To help others - trying providing the following. Assuming an input of "Britain" - what is `medalList` supposed to contain at the end of it, and what is its associated entry in `medals` ?

Comment: medalList is the variable name for the supposed returned list described above. at the end, it needs to have the number of medals that are associated with that particular country, the information of which is found in the dictionary medals that has been created in a previous function somestrng is supposed to index at that dictionary if it is contained within said dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def findMedals(countries, medals):
    code = raw_input("input a three letter country code and i'll see if I can find it: ")
    header = ['Country','Code','Gold','Silver','Bronze']
    entry = lambda c: [countries[c], c] + list(medals[c][1:]) # creates one table line
    if code == "":
        # wildcard -> add each line to table
        return [header] + [entry(c) for c in medals if c in countries]
    elif code in countries and code in medals:
        # valid code -> add one line to table
        return [header, entry(code)]
    else:
        # return 'invalid' line
        return [['INVALID CODE', 'n/a']]

countries = {"GER": "Germany", "GBR": "Breat Britain", "USA": "USA", "FOO": "No Medals"}
medals = {"GER": (0,1,2,3), "GBR": (3,4,5,6), "USA": (6,7,8,9)} # tuples, not sets!
res = findMedals(countries, medals)
for line in res:
    print "\t".join(map(str, line))
```

Some pointers:

- Your `for` loop is strange. You are iterating `items()`, i.e., tuples of key and values, not keys alone
- You are checking *in each iteration* whether the code is not in that tuple, i.e., that part will be executed once for each other country code; instead, just check *once* whether the code is a key `in` the dictionary
- You said that the `medals` dict maps codes to sets of numbers. This will not work, as sets are unordered, so there's no way to tell which of the numbers is the gold medals, which silver, etc. Use tutples or lists instead.
- While I assume that `medals` and `countries` will always hold the same codes, I added some checks to make sure.